# Netbeans Platform: Hide Tabs for just one TopComponent

Tags: java, tabs, netbeans-platform

netbeans platform has proved to be most useful for large applications. But what about small applications?

I'm building a small Price-List making software which only has one TopComponent which contains a JTable and a few buttons.

This component I've set to have closing/sliding etc disabled as this is mandatory to be there. I also DO NOT want to have ANY more top components.

Is there a way to remove the tabs? It seems pointles to show just one tab with the name of the TopComponent.

I hope you get what I mean!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Molten Ice,

Geertjan Wielenga's blog is an invaluable source of information for the NetBeans Platform.  He's written a post especially for this task:

http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/farewell_to_space_consuming_weird

I've used this technique before and it works fine.

If you have any other questions related to the NetBeans Platform I would suggest that you try the [Plaform Users](http://forums.netbeans.org/platform-users.html) section of the NetBeans forums.

Comment: I'd rather use the mailing list < dev@platform.netbeans.org > there are a lot of people that listen in on that, and will pipe up if they can help. I'm pretty sure that the forum and list do sync, but have seen some funnies with the syncing before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! Exactly what I was looking for. Honestly though I think I get much better and quicker feedback in Stack Overflow than Netbeans Platform Forum but I'll keep it in mind :)

Oh and I did search Geertjan's blog and had seen the 'Netbeans Platform for small applications' but never managed to find this post! :)